# Colouring cells in a Voronoi mesh

Tags: color, regions, mesh, style

Consider the following code

```
mesh = VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[1, {4, 2}]];
list = RandomReal[1, 4];
SetProperty[{mesh, {2, All}}, MeshCellStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ list]
```

which yields, for example, the following voronoi mesh

[image]

My goal is to let the `list` determine the opacity of a custom colour for each cell using `RGBColor`. I tried something like

```
MeshCellStyle -> RGBColor[.1,.1,.1,#] & /@ list
```

but it doesn't seem to work (all cells have the same colour). Any ideas?

Comment: use parenthesis 
MeshCellStyle -> (RGBColor[.1, .1, .1, #] & /@ list)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that on my system (V11.3 running on MacOS 10.13.4) setting the mesh style with `MeshCellStyle -> (RGBColor[.1, .1, .1, #] &) /@ list` results in a light blue wash, which is applied to all regions by default, tainting the grays produced for those cells where the opacity is low. This can corrected giving `VoronoiMesh` the option `BaseStyle -> Transparent`. Compare

```
SeedRandom[42]
mesh = VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[1, {4, 2}]];
list = RandomReal[1, 4];
SetProperty[{mesh, {2, All}}, MeshCellStyle -> (RGBColor[.1, .1, .1, #] &) /@ list]
```

[image: blue_tainted]

with

```
SeedRandom[42]
mesh = VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[1, {4, 2}], BaseStyle -> Transparent];
list = RandomReal[1, 4];
SetProperty[{mesh, {2, All}}, MeshCellStyle -> (RGBColor[.1, .1, .1, #] &) /@ list]
```

[image: true_gray]

Also, an alternative solution is

```
SeedRandom[42]
mesh = VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[1, {4, 2}], BaseStyle -> Transparent];
list = RandomReal[1, 4];
SetProperty[{mesh, {2, All}}, 
  MeshCellStyle -> (Directive[GrayLevel[.1], Opacity[#]] &) /@ list]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great. It's not the first time I come across this kind of OS differences. We even discussed something similar before (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211479/how-to-change-colour-of-togglerbar). I wonder if there is any documentation containing this type of observations.